# A method for showing the nonexistence of equivariant structure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

$\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}} \newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$
Suppose one is given a vector bundle $E \to X$ and a $G$ action on $X$.  Then can one show the nonexistence of a $G$-equivariant structure on the vector bundle $E$ by showing the nonexistence of a $G$-action on a certain vector space?

For example, we have the canonical action of $PGL(n+1)$ on $\P^n$ given by descending the action of $GL(n+1)$ on $\P^n$.   $O(1)$ can be viewed as a subbundle of $\P^n \times \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ of points of the form $([v],v)$. There is an obvious $GL(n+1)$ equivariant structure send$g([v],v)=([gv],gv)$.  I think that one should be able to show the nonexistence of an equivariant structure by showing the nonexistence of an action of $PGL(n+1)$ on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.

Comment: If you had a $PGL(n+1)$ structure on this subbundle, why should you be able to extend it to a $PGL(n+1)$-structure on the trivial bundle it lives in?

Comment: yes - there is no way to put a PGL(n+1) structure on the quotient bundle.  On the other hand I found the right vector space to work with.  The space of global sections of $\mathcal{O}(1) =\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ would have a (possibly trivial) action by $PGL(n+1)$ if there was an equivariant structure.  It can't have a nontrivial action.  If it had a trivial action, then then $\O(1)$ would be trivial.